# How to pass variables to forms generated by gui buider

Tags: codenameone

I have a LandingForm that was created by GUI builder and Form2 also created by builder.

LandingForm has a Multilist which is dynamically built by an arraylist. So on click a lambda expression invokes Form2. I modified Form2 constructor to get variable.

The variable is null in Form2

Comment: How does the event code look and how did you change the constructor? Notice you can edit your answer to include those code blocks and then you should comment here with a response so I will notice the edit

Comment: dont worry i had to create a form programmatically as a work around